# Changing font using CSS in Qualtrics

Tags: css, fonts, qualtrics

I'm uber new to using CSS code (almost zero experience) and have been tasked to changing the font style and size of my Qualtrics survey.

I need:

- Font style: Arial
- Question Text size: 14
- Question choice size: 12

Can anybody help, please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

According to this page: [Fonts and Colors](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/basic-building/look-and-feel/fonts-and-colors/), changing the `font-family` and `font-size` is also possible without using CSS.

However if you do want to use CSS, use the following code:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.Skin .QuestionText {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

More info: [Qualtrics-forms.css](https://stash.development.wvu.edu/projects/CST/repos/code/browse/stylesheets/qualtrics/1.0/qualtrics-forms.css?at=master)